# When is the completion timer counting?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

In order to get the last skull in a level, your completion time must beat the par time for that level. When is the timer to determine your completion time counting?

Does it count when:

- Selecting equipment (When the message "Press B key to select your traps" is on-screen)?
- Building traps between waves and at the beginning?
- In the pause menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=27121075&postcount=2)

> Yeah, the initial setup is off the clock but once the first wave starts the clock keeps going through the breaks including the ones where you press G to continue. The pause menu and the weaver menu (as you noted) do stop the clock.

[Other resources](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/665786-orcs-must-die-2/63607009) have also confirmed this. In summation:

- Initial setup is not part of completion time.
- The pause menu is not part of completion time.
- Everything else until you complete the level is part of your completion time.

Comment: Beat me to it. I believe that the Weaver menu is restricted to only Orcs Must Die (the first game).

Comment: Correct. I have made that adjustment. This same post by Smeggit [is accurate to OMD2 as well](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/665786-orcs-must-die-2/63607009) and applies to the series in general. It looks like Robot Entertainment smartly kept it the same for both games.

Comment: Nice information about the option to show the timer. I didn't know that myself.